# ¿Cómo puedo realizar una conexión a una base de datos MySQL con PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentado crear una conexión a mi base de datos mediante el siguiente código PHP. Sin embargo, me da error y no sé cuál es.

el error que me da es: algo ha ido mal en la consula a la base de datos

¿Me podríais ayudar?

```
<?php
    // Ejemplo de conexión a base de datos MySQL con PHP.


    // Datos de la base de datos
    $usuario = "";
    $password = "";
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $basededatos = "";

    // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
    $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

    // Selección de la base de datos a utilizar
    $db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
    // establecer y realizar consulta. guardamos en variable.
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM spain";
    $resultado = mysqli_query( $conexion, $consulta ) or die ( "Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");

    // Motrar el resultado de los registro de la base de datos
    // Encabezado de la tabla
    echo <table borde='1'>;
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Team</th>";
    echo "<th>Played</th>";
    echo "<th>Wins</th>";
    echo "<th>Deals</th>";
    echo "<th>Losts</th>";
    echo "<th>Goals</th>";
    echo "<th>Diff</th>";
    echo "<th>Points</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    // Bucle while que recorre cada registro y muestra cada campo en la tabla.
    while ($columna = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado ))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $columna['nombre'] . "</td><td>" . $columna['edad'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>"; 
    // Fin de la tabla
    // cerrar conexión de base de datos
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da exactamente? Intenta proporcionar un [mcve]

Comment: me aparece en mensaje: algo a ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos

Comment: dale pues a [edit] y añade esta información a tu pregunta. Cuanto más expliques, mejor te podremos ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te falta definir la conexión a la BD , prueba con este trozo de código y dinos que te dice

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "base_de_datos");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: conectando al servidor MYSQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

Comment: hola buenas! te aparece bien el codigo? yo use el siguiente codigo: // creación de la conexión a la base de datos con mysql_connect()
 $conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");

Comment: hola @ilernet no entendia lo que me decias pero ahora si, acabo de poner lo de la base de datos y me da el siguiente error: ( Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\xampp\htdocs\frogak\2.php on line 22 ) que es donde pongo para crear la tabla.

Comment: @ImanolGarmendia ese error esta en esta linea `echo <table borde='1'>;` te faltan las comillas asi `echo "<table borde='1'>";`

Comment: @ImanolGarmendia La base de datos es un parámetro opcional (o debería serlo) y hacías `mysqli_select_db` justo después. Parece raro que sólo eso resuelva el problema. Además, el `mysqli_select_db` no lanzaba error, sino el `mysqli_query` que viene después. ¿Has cambiado algo en el código aparte de eso?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro alfinal he utilizado otro codigo que no puedo ponerlo aqui. Pero me da un error en el apartado de:$result = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from mi DB");  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) y me pone lo siguiente: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean. Y nose cual es el problema

Comment: @ImanolGarmendia El problema es que hay un error en la select. Busca en el sitio porque hay preguntas resueltas con el mismo problema. En ese caso, parece que estás haciendo “select * from miDB” cuando debería ser “select * from miTAbla”. Que me estoy imaginando era el fallo inicial.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro si Alvaro, puse mal sin querer pero si que tengo puesto mitabla y aun y todo me da y nose porque, ya que hice lo mismo con otra tabla y me sale bien y en cambio he probado con dos y me da el mismo error poniendo bien el nombre de la tabla